# How to change the signalr entry point of blazor server side from _blazor to _new_blazor

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-signalr

I am building a web app using blazor server side rendering. I also would like to use different signal connection for each subpath of the website. For example:

- https://example.com/product-detail -> use signalr path `_product_detail_blazor`
- https://example.com/product-category -> use signalr path `_product_category_blazor`

I think on the server code, we can set the path:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    ...
    endpoints.MapBlazorHub("/_product_detail_blazor");
    ...
});
```

But I don't know how to tell client side to connect to that path:

```
/_product_detail_blazor?id=wNzkjIsL123Obe43rvK810g
```

By default it connects to:

```
/_blazor?id=wNzkjIsL123Obe43rvK810g
```

Thank

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to avoid adding `<base href>` by using a couple of hacks, but so far, everything works.

First, in my _Layout.cshtml (as I've added blazor components to existing MVC app, .NET6) I need to stop Blazor from autostarting and I need to tell signalR where to look:

```cs
<script src="~/_framework/blazor.server.js" autostart="false"></script>
<script>
Blazor.start({
        configureSignalR: function (builder) {
            builder.withUrl("/_blazor", {
                
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

And then, because `/_blazor/initializers` path is hardcoded in Blazor, and without base-tag it will not find it if you navigate away from root page, I needed to do a dirty rewrite in my program.cs:

```cs
var rewriteOptions = new RewriteOptions();
    rewriteOptions.AddRewrite("_blazor/initializers", "/_blazor/initializers", skipRemainingRules: true);
    app.UseRewriter(rewriteOptions);
```

That seems to work fine so far. Seems like Blazor was meant to be an exclusive front end rather than something you should integrate into existing MVC projects, as some of the config that Blazor needs, can and does affect the operation of the MVC as a whole, for example with base-tag being "mandatory".

Comment: Hello, I am facing the same issue.
I am using .NET 6 for an important asp.net mvc project, where we believed it was possible to add Blazor components, but we are stuck with this issue.
Is there solution, at this moment?

Answer (score 1):

Blazor assumes everything to run at a base path. You can set the base path using `<base href="..." />`. For example to host Blazor under `/spa`:

```cs
endpoints.MapBlazorHub("/spa/_blazor");
```

```html
<base href="/spa/" />
```

I'm not aware of a (supported) method to separate the base path from the blazor hub's URL, you're probably swimming against the stream trying to get that to work.

**Previous incorrect answer:**

You can by opting out of autostart. I'm doing something along the same lines with .NET 6. There's a caveat however, the path to `blazor/_initializers` is [hard-coded and cannot be changed](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/a450cb69b5e4549f5515cdb057a68771f56cefd7/src/Components/Web.JS/src/JSInitializers/JSInitializers.Server.ts#L6). So you need two registrations, one will be used for hosting the websocket, the other for the initializers:

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    ...
    endpoints.MapBlazorHub("/_product_detail_blazor");
    endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
    ...
});
```

To opt out of autostart and specify your custom endpoint:

```html
<script src="/_framework/blazor.server.js" autostart="false"></script>
<script>
    Blazor.start({
        configureSignalR: builder => {
            builder.withUrl("_product_detail_blazor");
        }
    });
</script>
```

I've reported this issue [with the ASP.NET Core Team](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38545).